# appcelerator Calendar view

Tags: titanium, google-calendar-api, appcelerator-mobile

I want to implement calendar in my app from which I can set specific events on specific time same as shown in image. I want to do it in titanium please guide me what I have to do for it.Thanks.[image]

Comment: flagged as too broad, pelase read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is broad, but either way the answer it to start building it yourself.  Each rectangle can be a view as well as each box representing days.  The bottom has a tableview on it and then a bar with a button bar in it.  Add some labels and a backgroundImage and you are pretty close to this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this Titanium Module [TimeSquare calendar picker](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.SQ). There are some Calendar View UI modules out there available through the [Appcelerator Marketplace](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/listing?2106974862&q=calendar#!/list/page/1/search=calendar).

Judging from the screenshots you've posted I'm supposing you want to build an iOS app but **before you start** carefully check README file for platform specifications, Titanium SDK support and any other development considerations.